# Remove ubuntu one from messaging indicator

Tags: ubuntu-one, indicator

I have been trying to find a way to remove the Ubuntu One entry from the indicators' panel.

I have removed the `ubuntuone` file from `/usr/share/indicators/applications`
and edited it out of the `seendb.keyfile` in `~/cache/indicators/messages/`
but it keeps returning.

I just want it gone, as I do not need it at all.
How can I do it? I have Ubuntu Natty amd64.

Answer (score 10):

If instead of [blacklisting the menu item](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58413/remove-ubuntu-one-from-messaging-indicator/58415#58415) you completely want to get rid of Ubuntu One, remove the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol
```

After logging out and in again, Ubuntu One (and the menu item) should be gone.

Comment: On a multiuser computer, removing UbuntuOne may not be viable. Who uses it, though? ;)

Comment: @htorque I have removed whatever Ubuntu one I can remove from software center. Now what command should I use to delete that icon?

Answer (score 5):

User a terminal and make the directory

`mkdir -p ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist/`

Files in here should be paths to .desktop files which will be blacklsited on startup. The .desktop files in question are located in

`/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications`

so you can make symlinks from there to this directory. Thus

`ln -s /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/menuItem ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist/menuItem`

will remove `menuItem` from the messaging menu. Run

`ls /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications`

to see what the names of the .desktop files are and look for the one mentioning Ubuntu One.

You can run

`killall gnome-panel`

to see the changes immediately. Else, a logout should work as well.

Comment: yes what you said does ok.... kind of but if you run the ubuntu one app after doing what you have said the menuItem returns (for me anyway) it has even returned after it has notified me that files have been uploaded or downloaded to my system? very strange. maybe there is no way other than purging U1 completely to get rid of U1, which is a pain as I still would like to use ubuntu one. maybe I might have to move to dropbox instead? or just get used to having a useless item in the indicator-messages menu?.

Answer (score 0):

Now that Ubuntu One is dying, I wanted to remove the Ubuntu One indicator. I realized that the above methods either hide the indicator or remove the application, not the indicator itself.

So to remove the Ubuntu One indicator from the top menu bar:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-ubuntuone
```